# Settings an Accept Type which has a parameter

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I need to set the Accept header of a GET request to a media type that has a parameter such as `application/json; model=v2`.  Attempts to utilize `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` result in a `FormatException` with Message

> "The format of value 'application/json; model=v3' is invalid".

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpClient c = new HttpClient(handler);
// throws below
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json; model=v3"));
string json = await c.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44303/config.svc/clients/18.1.2.1");
```

This approach works well enough when utilizing `HttpWebRequest` where the Accept header is a string.  Is it possible to coerce HttpClient to accept this value as a valid Accept header.

**Update**

The parameters cannot be set via the constructor but instead via the [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.parameters(v=vs.118).aspx) property on the constructed instance.

```
var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
mediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("model","v3"));
```

Comment: did you look at the MSDN documentation on this [MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypewithqualityheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx) 2 overloads 1 takes a string the other takes a string and a double.. try it with just `("application/json")`

Comment: The double is the value qualifier to help negotiate which type to use if the client and server had more than one they both supported.  I.e. yes xml will work but json is preferred.

Comment: @MethodMan Good point about the documentation though I missed the [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.parameters(v=vs.118).aspx) property on the constructed `MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue` instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MethodMan suggesion some judicious use of the documentation identified the [Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.mediatypeheadervalue.parameters(v=vs.118).aspx) Property on the constructed instance.  The ctor apparently can only handle the declaration of type/subtypes.

```
var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
mediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("model","v3"));
```